# Need help in comparing 2 xml files using XMLUnit ignoring spaces in differences

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I have a code in java comparing 2 xml files using XMLUnit. It is highlighting the differences for a extra space in one of the lines which I wish to ignore. How can I achieve this.

Below are the settings used.

```
XMLUnit.setCompareUnmatched(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
XMLUnit.setNormalize(true);
```

For Example:
xml1:

`<metadata><div><p>This is a test</p></div></metadata>`

xml2:

`<metadata><div><p>This is a test</p> </div></metadata>`

The space between `</p>` and `</div>` tags is highlighted in above example.

Comment: Try `XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);` and/or `XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true);`

Comment: Sorry I missed to add `XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);` which is already part of my code. Tried `XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true);`, didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

The space after the `p` tag is a text node by itself so it might not be possible to remove or ignore it by configuration.

```
xmllint --shell test.xml

/ > xpath /metadata/div/descendant-or-self::*/text()
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 2 nodes:
1  TEXT
    content=This is a test
2  TEXT
    content=  
/ >
```

Getting each text node:

```
echo "'$(xmllint --xpath '(/metadata/div/descendant-or-self::*/text())[1]' test.xml)'"
'This is a test'

echo "'$(xmllint --xpath '(/metadata/div/descendant-or-self::*/text())[2]' test.xml)'"
'  '
```

From the [normalize-space() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space)

> The normalize-space function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string.

From [setIgnoreWhitespace(boolean ignore) XMLUnit docs](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/XMLUnit.html#setIgnoreWhitespace%28boolean%29)

> Setting this parameter has no effect on whitespace inside texts.

Also on same docs

> Normalized in this context means that all whitespace is replaced by the space character and adjacent whitespace characters are collapsed to a single space character. It will also trim the resulting character content on both ends.